# float left or display inline-block is not working in styled components reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

[image: Here is the image with correct alignment]

I want to get the image and text in the same div I have tried using float left and display inline-block but of no use I cant get the mistake where I am doing.

I am getting the output as follows
[image: Here is the image after writing code I get it]

I used styled components in reactjs. 
These are the styled components I have used

```
export const BannerContainer = styled.div`
    width: 1280px
    height: 448px
    margin: auto
    `
```

export const BannerImageContainer = styled.div
        `height:448px
        width:640px
        float: left`

export const BannerImage = styled.img
        `padding:96px 96px 96px 96px
        margin-left:128px`

export const BannerTextContainer = styled.div
        `height:448px
        width:512px
        margin-right:128px
        float: left`

export const BannerHeaderText = styled.h1
        `width: 352px
        height: 64px
        padding-top:40px
        font-family: Nunito
        font-size: 28px
        font-weight: 600
        line-height: 1.14
        text-align: center`

export const BannerParagraphContainer = styled.p
        `width: 389px
        height: 72px
        opacity: 0.38
        font-family: Nunito
        font-size: 16px
        line-height: 1.5
        text-align: center
        color: #000000`

export const SeeAllProductsButton = styled.button
        `width: 160px
        height: 32px
        background-color: #7C6ECC
        color: #FFFFFF
        border: 0px
        margin: 32px 112px`

This is the code for rendering it
            `<BannerContainer>
                <BannerImageContainer>
                    <BannerImage src={bannerImage} />
                </BannerImageContainer>
                <BannerTextContainer>
                    <BannerHeaderText>
                        Solving the most common problems in marketing
                    </BannerHeaderText>
                    <BannerParagraphContainer>
                        Exquisite codially mr happiness of neglected distrusts.
                        Boisterous impossible unaffected he me everything.
                    </BannerParagraphContainer>
                    <SeeAllProductsButton>See All Products</SeeAllProductsButton>
                </BannerTextContainer>
            </BannerContainer>`

Answer (score 1):

Try using FlexBox!

Very simple implementation to get you going:

```
<div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
   <div style={{flex: '1'}}>
      <BannerImageContainer>
          <BannerImage src={bannerImage} />
      </BannerImageContainer>
   </div>
   <div style={{flex: '1'}}>
      <BannerTextContainer>
          <BannerHeaderText>
              Solving the most common problems in marketing
          </BannerHeaderText>
          <BannerParagraphContainer>
             Exquisite codially mr happiness of neglected distrusts.
             Boisterous impossible unaffected he me everything.
          </BannerParagraphContainer>
          <SeeAllProductsButton>See All Products</SeeAllProductsButton>
      </BannerTextContainer>
   </div>
</div>
```

Just to add a bit more info, this is a really popular css component (not specific to React) for aligning things properly. Just googling 'flexbox' will give you a lot of info, but some specific links are [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Does it just do nothing?

Comment: It is doing but the alignment is not correct while checking it in elements of developer tools.... the container is totally going aside.... I think it should not be like that. The alignment in developer tools should also be perfect....right?

Comment: Right in that case i'm not sure how to help anymore. Hope someone else comes by who knows more about this.